# How to list what transforms @babel/preset-env includes?

Tags: babeljs

I like how I can use http://browserl.ist/ to see what browsers the `targets` query will target in `@babel/preset-env`.

Is there any similar tools to list what Babel plugins (transforms etc.) the env preset actually includes?

I'm using Webpack as my bundler if it matters.

Comment: How would that be possible? The package contains all available transforms whereas what is actually being applied depends on your `.babelrc`.

Comment: For example with some cli tool which reads your `.babelrc`. Doesn't need to be a web site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try add `debug:true` in `@babel/preset-env` options, it will list all plugin in use

```json
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "debug": true,
        "targets": {
          "chrome": 49,
          "firefox": 64,
          "safari": 9,
          "edge": 13,
          "ios": 9
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can always check out the source for [@babel/preset-env](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-preset-env/src), namely the [available-plugins.js](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/master/packages/babel-preset-env/src/available-plugins.js) file lists the available plugins in the preset.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a simple config in your .babelrc or babel.config.js file.

```
"@babel/preset-env",
  {
    useBuiltIns: "usage",
    debug: true, // this will make babel output actual transform plugins and polyfills in terminal
    targets: {
      chrome: "53",
    },
    corejs: 3,
  },
```

But this will not work when you use webpack

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @rabidpug, [available-plugins.js](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/master/packages/babel-preset-env/src/available-plugins.js) lists all plugins.

However, which ones are being used depend on your config.

E.g.:

- The `shippedProposals` config option is `false` by default. As per [index.js](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/8b1bcd1079415516e9c74b2daadd34c159f31c16/packages/babel-preset-env/src/index.js#L60), this already eliminates all files as listed in [data/shipped-proposals.js](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/672a58660f0b15691c44582f1f3fdcdac0fa0d2f/packages/babel-preset-env/data/shipped-proposals.js).
- Similarly, the recently added `bugfixes` option adds more plugins (until babel@8 comes along), listed in [`@babel/compat-data/plugin-bugfixes`](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/master/packages/babel-compat-data/data/plugin-bugfixes.json).

## Solution

Luckily, `preset-env` has a `debug` option that just prints out all plugins used when the preset is invoked.

Just add `debug` to your [`preset-env` options](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#options) and it will list all plugins (and more).

For convinience, I wrote this little script that independently debugs your `plugins` list (given a custom set of `preset-env` options). Run it using `node list-preset-env-plugins.js` in a folder where you have `babel` installed:

```js
// list-preset-env-plugins.js

const babelCore = require('@babel/core');
const presetEnv = require('@babel/preset-env').default;

/**
 * Your preset-env options.
 * @see https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#options
 */
const presetEnvOptions = {
  shippedProposals: true,
  debug: true
};

/**
 * @see https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/master/packages/babel-helper-plugin-utils/src/index.js
 */
const apiStub = {
  version: babelCore.version,
  assertVersion() { }
};

// invoke the preset
presetEnv(apiStub, presetEnvOptions);
```